# Script times out even with set_time_limit(0) PHP/Apache

Tags: php, apache

I set time limit for my scrip to 0 so it can take as long as it needs:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

When I run the script after few minutes it times out and returns **500 Internal Server Error** with the following error from apache **error_log**:

```
 Script timed out before returning headers: index.php
```

How can I increase timeout from PHP code and not touching **httpd.conf** or **php.ini** file. I dont have access to those files.

Comment: That error suggests your PHP is running as a CGI handler, not as an Apache module. In this case, the CGI wrapper script controls the lifetime and PHP cannot influence it. Only your server administrator can change the wrapper settings. But you should restructure your code so that long-running processes like this are started by an external process (e.g. crontab-based job runner), not by the webserver. That way limitations like this will not get in your way.

Comment: @DCoder I have access to admin CPanel, how would I increase the limit ?

Comment: That depends on which CGI wrapper you are using to run your PHP code, and I doubt CPanel will expose the necessary settings. But I don't work with CPanel, so I can't comment for sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set `max_execution_time` via `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`.

If this doesn't work and you do not have access to php.ini, I consider your script runs on a (shared) host you have no full access to configuration files. If so, propably your host does not allow you to overwrite the time limit with`set_time_limit` (are you running php in safe mode?). This would make it impossible to change these values.

Instead, try to refactor your script so it doesnt need so much time.